# searchcursor only takes first value in field

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

My script ArcGIS 10.2 is using the searchcursor to read the mLanduse feature class to return the value in lField, but it is only returning the first value in lField to populate the sField in mSoils.

```
# Loop through the rows and update the blank sField values in mSoils
# with the lFields from mLanduse
     for row in cursor:
         with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mSoils, sField, "SoilType = ' '") as cursor2:
             for row2 in cursor2:
                 row2[0] = row[0]
                 row = cursor.next()
```

Comment: try http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74325/arcpy-nested-loop-problem

Comment: I'm already using da.SearchCursor.

Comment: Have u tried with if row2[0] == None:

Comment: Weird, only fills every second blank field in sField with first value of lField.

Comment: Can u post snapshot of ur attribute tables with table filed type (e.g. String, Double etc.)

Comment: Both table has equal number of rows?

Comment: OK the let alone nested cursor, and try http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109787/updatecursor-only-takes-last-value-of-searchcursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, the problem here is that you want to do a spatial join (based on location) but you are using a method for table join (based on a "key" field). Indeed, there does not seem to be a key field and you don't have the same number of feature, so you will not be able to get the match based on your attributes. I suggest that you start with [arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) and the match option "within", then you can update your empty fields with your update cursor. The disadvantage of the method is that it creates a new feature class, so you could also use the [geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000070000000) within your cursor, but I have no time to write the script.